# Start jade via batch script as service on windows server 2012 amazon ec2 instance

Tags: windows, command-line, java, batch, services

I would like to start the Jade agent platform with a batch script on an windows server ec2 instance as a service. The reason for this is, that I want to start jade automatically at system startup.

For creating the service I use nssm. However so far its working fine and the service is created.
When I want to start the service I get an error message:

> Windows could not start the NAME service on Local Computer. The
>   service did not return an error...

My batch file contains only one line:

> java jade.Boot -platform-id P%random%

If i execute the script via cmd it works fine.

Anybody got an idea why this is not working if I start the batch script as a service?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to grant Administrator rights to the service because jade uses network services.